# Form Auth and Custom Error

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, custom-errors

I have application that is using Form Authentication. It has deny tag in the root web config file.

```
 <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

The application File structure has CSS and JS folder. Now When I try access CSS and JS folder (`https://domainname/CSS`) it is redirecting me to login page. This ensure that presence of directory in the site. I want to show custom error page in this case.

Also, when I try to access `https://domainname/bin` URL it is redirecting me to HTTP 404 Error.

How to show same custom error page on both cases?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used form authentication any unauthorized request will redirect to the page you specified in `loginUrl` of form authentication

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
```

But for error pages like 404 or 500 or any other you can congigure pages to show when an error occurs.Add this to web.config to configure error pages

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch an unauthorized request in one of the application events in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, 
                                                    EventArgs e)
{
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
 if (!Request.IsAuthenticated || url.Contains("Check Your URL Here")) 
 Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx"); 
}
```